# Java SuperClass and SubClass extending comparable

Tags: java, sorting, subclass, superclass

I am doing this assignment where we have to create 2 types of object,

```
public class Person implements Cloneable, Comparable<Person>
```

and

```
public class Book implements Cloneable, Comparable<Book>
```

The main task of this program is to sort the two types using its own compare functions as following:

```
compareTo(Person o)
compareTo(Book o)
```

So, I created 2 ListArray as following in the main function to store the book and person objects as following:

```
List<Book> bookArray = new ArrayList<Book>();
List<Person> peopleArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And I have my sorting algorithm implemented in another class like the following:

```
public class Sort{
Comparable<Object>[] values;
public Sort(List<Object> inputArray) {
  this.values = (Comparable<Object>[]) inputArray.toArray();
}
public doSort() {
  //sort implementation...
}
```

The problem is when calling this function using the arrays above

```
Sort sorter = new Sort(peopleArray);
sorter.doSort();
```

Eclipse shows the error saying "The constructor Sort(List) is undefined."
What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `public class Sort extends {` extends what?

Comment: sorry it doesn't extend anything

Comment: The "proper" way to implement this is using generics, but barring that, what happens if you cast the peopleArray to List<Object> when you pass it to the constructor?

Comment: It complains. I need to do `List<Person> peopleArray = ArrayList<Person>;`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any class instance to Object type. but List is not a parent of List. Those are just two different types.

You can say

```
public Sort(List<? extends Object> inputArray)
```

so that it will accept any type.

Comment: Ok. It solved the type problem, so the program is runnable without error. However, it throws an exception when it runs to the constructor of `public Sort(List<? extends Object> inputArray)`. It says "Object cannot be cast to comparable." I know it's because both `Person` and `Book` extends `Comparable`, but how do I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Just because you *named* the field "personArray" does not *make* it an array - you are passing in a `List` when the constructor is declared to expect an array.

I recommend that you never use arrays unless you absolutely have to; use Collections instead, because they are *so* much easier to deal with and, contrary to popular belief, the performance difference is negligible.

If you remove all arrays from your code, and add some generics, it will all work:

```
public class Sort<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private List<T> values;

    public Sort(List<T> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void doSort() {
        Collections.sort(values);
    }
}
```

Note that this whole class adds very little value, if sorting is all it does. Your client code can just code this one line instead:

```
Collections.sort(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not so clear but If am right Whenevr you use another new class for sorting that is probably implements COMPARATOR.

so in ur example Sort class should be

```
Class Sort implemets Comaparator<Person> {
public void Compare(Object 01,Object 02) {
 return (Person)o1.comapareTo(Person)o2;
}
```

then in `main`, call

```
Collections.sort(list,new Sort());
```

lly u need to do for book too.